# See if two objects are the same where one attribute has a different order using Chai

Tags: javascript, chai, equality

I have two object arrays:

```javascript
array1 = [ 
  { name: 'Kitty, Hello',
    otherNames: [ '(1) One', '(2) Two' ] 
  },
  { name: 'Cat, Garfield',
    otherNames: [ '(3) Three' ] 
  } 
];

array2 = [ 
  { name: 'Kitty, Hello',
    otherNames: [ '(2) Two', '(1) One' ] 
  },
  { name: 'Cat, Garfield', 
    otherNames: [ '(3) Three' ] 
   } 
]
```

I am trying to use Chai to see if they are equal, despite `otherNames` being in a different order in `array1` and `array2 .

I have tried:

```javascript
array1.to.be.eql(array2) //false
array1.to.have.deep.members(array2) //false
```

But it keeps returning false. Is this even possible? I have tried looking at similar questions, but I could only find questions where "name" and "otherNames" were in different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well they are not equals since they have different values in the array. You can sort the array and check if they are equal then.

```js
const getSortedAtKey = (array, key = 'otherNames') => {
  return array.map(value => ({
    ...value,
    [key]: value[key].sort()
  }));
}

expect(getSortedAtKey(array1)).to.eql(getSortedAtKey(array2))
```

This function is nice since you can chain it for multiple properties (if you have for example `otherNames` and `otherAges` arrays that you want to verify you can call `getSortedAtKey(getSortedAtKey(array1), 'otherAges')`

Comment: I see, I had thought I could do something that says its included in the object, just not in the correct order.

Sorting it solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for that.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal-in-any-order

```
const deepEqualInAnyOrder = require('deep-equal-in-any-order');
const chai = require('chai');

chai.use(deepEqualInAnyOrder);

const { expect } = chai;

expect(array1).to.deep.equalInAnyOrder(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the initial post were more recent, I would suggest that @webdesignnoob reconsider his design. Broadly, this question pertains to the concept of equivalence among objects.

Within the @ut8pia/classifier library, equivalence can be implemented through a representation function:

```js
const 
  objRepr = obj => [obj.name, ...obj.otherNames.sort()],
  arrayRepr = array => array.map(objRepr).flat().join(', '),
  
  equal = TrueSet.of(arrayRepr, ORDER.ASCENDING, ORDER.SINGULAR)
    .let(array1)
      .has(array2)
```

The library claims to address the long-standing need for sorted collections in JavaScript. For a detailed explanation, please refer to the [online documentation](https://ut8pia.github.io/classifier).